# "A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid" ONLY when I deploy remotely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

Works perfectly locally on IIS, as soon as I deploy to my production or staging server, every single anti forgery request fails with the above error message EXCEPT I can log on (which uses the attribute).

I've tried deleting cookies, and setting a static machine key, nothing has worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If only I could give rep to encourage an answer without having to wait 2 days :(

Comment: Token should be stored in cookie and in hidden field inside form. Maybe you are setting @Html.Antiforgerytoken twice. In my form there is difference between token stored in cookie and that in hidden field.

Comment: It's definitely there just once, as it works locally. In the end I wrote my own version which is working great, but I'll leave the question open in case someone in the future figures it out.

Comment: Are you using simple membership?